# How to batch copy "date modified" from files in directory to other files with identical names (but compressed) in another directory?

Tags: batch, metadata, copy, date-modified

I have been compressing my 500++ MP4 videos from 2 years ago with Handbrake, however, as the compressed files are registered as new files, they do not retain their original metadata attributes (date modified, date created, etc).

I'd like to batch copy the metadata from the original files to the compressed ones, especially the date modified. The files have identical names, only located in different directory.

BulkFileChanger can batch modify dates, but it can't copy dates from other files.

Comment: What kind of compression does this handbreak use? You can use the command line tool robocopy to copy the files with original dates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the command line program, [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/), you would use this command
`exiftool -TagsFromFile /path/to/sourceFiles/%F -All:All -FileModifyDate -FileCreateDate /Path/to/NewFiles/`

This will copy all embedded tags that exiftool can copy as well as the system timestamps from the `/path/to/sourceFiles/` directory to files with the **exact** same name in the `/Path/to/NewFiles/` directory.

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.

Comment: This does not copy the file attributes in the operating system. And the old metadata can make the file unplayable.

Comment: What metadata do you believe will make it unplayable?  There are things that exiftool can't copy, but the things that it can will not make it unplayable.

Comment: Video length and other stuff. In any case, this does not seem to be what the poster is asking.

Comment: Exiftool does not edit the video stream, so it cannot change properties of the streams such as length, size, frame rate, etc. See [here](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html) for full list of what exiftool can edit in a video file.

Comment: I tested this with other videos and I got error. What did I do wrong? https://i.imgur.com/OvljQIX.png

Comment: Exiftool can't find the original files in the path you gave.  Make sure that the file listed is in the ` BlackSkylands`  directory with the exact same name.  If the file is in a sub-directory or has a different filename, for example, is an AVI instead of a MP4, then the command will have to be adjusted.

Comment: @StarGeek ok I missed that. That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[BulkFileChanger](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html) can do it now since Version 1.65.

[BulkFileChanger - Change file time / attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0AlF.png)

> BulkFileChanger now allows you to change and copy the date/time values > stored inside media files ( .mp4 , .mov). You can change/copy 3 date/time values: Item Date, Date Encoded, Date Acquired.